# Como passar um post com um array para uma URL de um WebFORM

Tags: c#, webforms, post

Estou tentando mandar um array com alguns elementos em um post para uma url.

Chamei método 'WebBroser', passei os parâmetros, mas mesmo assim fiquei sem ideia de como terminar de implementar.

Segue meu código:

```
   private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("MINHA_URL");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.UserAgent = "curl/7.37.0";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string data = "browser=Win7x64-C1|Chrome32|1024x768&url=http://www.google.com";

            streamWriter.Write(data);
        }

    }
    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lista = new string[]
        {
            info.nome,
            info.idade,
              info.estado= "H",
           //DAQUI PRA BAIXO JÁ É PRÉ-DEFINIDO

            info.regiao,
            info.tipousuario = "X",
            info.formulario = "0",
            info.t = "+",
            info.v = "",
            info.pop = "",
            info.t= "",
            info.p= "",
            info.t= "x",
            info.r= "x",
            info.e= "2",
            info.f= "n",
            info.id= ""
        };

         webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(lista, null);
    }

    #region inputs
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        info.estado= textBox1.Text;
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        info.nome= textBox2.Text;
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        info.idade= textBox3.Text;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é sua dúvida.

Comment: Então cigano. Tenho uma URL que vai receber um post de um array. O que quero é, mandar esse post que está no button1_Click para o método webBrowser1_DocumentComplete.

Comment: E depois? O que acontece?

Comment: Desejo que essa url, execute com os parâmetros que foi enviado a ela.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente está tudo certo. Falta só recolher a resposta:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("MINHA_URL");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.UserAgent = "curl/7.37.0";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string data = "browser=Win7x64-C1|Chrome32|1024x768&url=http://www.google.com";

        streamWriter.Write(data);
    }

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
}
```

Comment: Valeu, vou testar assim que puder. E te dou um feedback. Obrigadão!

Comment: aconteceu o seguinte erro:' A conexão subjacente estava fechada: A conexão foi fechada de modo inesperado.'

Comment: Esse bug acontece por alguma característica diferente no cabeçalho do retorno. Experimente usar `request.KeepAlive = false;`. Já atualizei a resposta.

Comment: continua dando o erro de "A conexão foi fechada..." E outra dúvida. em string data = "browser=Win7x64-C1|Chrome32|1024x768&url=MINHA_URL"; Nessa parte da "minha_url" eu coloco a url q passo no Create, n é?